# Why does the self.search() return None while being called by thesingleNonDuplicate() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting None as return value, the code doesn't work as expected, search() returns None in line 4. Why?

I am trying to call a search() function inside a function of a class. Theer seems to be a problem with the inner function returning to the outer one.

```
class Solution:
def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums):
    n = len(nums)
    ans = self.search(nums, 0, n-1)
    return ans

def search(self,l,low,high):

    if low == high:             # base case
        return (l[high])


    else:
        mid = low + (high-low)//2         # evaluate mid


        if mid%2 == 0:

            if l[mid] == l[mid + 1]:
                self.search(l,mid+2,high)

            else:
                self.search(l,low,mid)

        else:

            if l[mid] != l[mid+1]:
                self.search(l,mid+1,high)
            else:
                self.search(l,low,mid)
```

Comment: because you only return from it the ``search`` method when low == high - but you don't return in other places too ? my guess would be you should be returning the value of self.search in all places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing returns from the rest of your recursive function - every time you recurse (called self.search) you have to return the value - and eventually that result will make it up the chain.

```
class Solution:
   def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums):
     n = len(nums)
     ans = self.search(nums, 0, n-1)
     return ans

  def search(self,l,low,high):

     if low == high:             # base case
       return (l[high])
     else:
       mid = low + (high-low)//2         # evaluate mid

       if mid%2 == 0:
          if l[mid] == l[mid + 1]:
             return self.search(l,mid+2,high)
          else:
             return self.search(l,low,mid)
       else:
          if l[mid] != l[mid+1]:
              return self.search(l,mid+1,high)
          else:
              return self.search(l,low,mid)
```